# Exploding pipe separated data in spark

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a spark dataframe(**input_dataframe**), data in this dataframe looks like as below:

```
id              value
 1                a
 2                x|y|z
 3                t|u
```

I want to have **output_dataframe**, having pipe separated fields exploded and it should look like below:

```
id              value
 1                a
 2                x
 2                y
 2                z
 3                t
 3                u
```

Please help me achieving the desired solution using PySpark. Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

we can first split and then explode the value column using functions as below,

```
>>> l=[(1,'a'),(2,'x|y|z'),(3,'t|u')]
>>> df = spark.createDataFrame(l,['id','val'])
>>> df.show()
+---+-----+
| id|  val|
+---+-----+
|  1|    a|
|  2|x|y|z|
|  3|  t|u|
+---+-----+

>>> from pyspark.sql import functions as F
>>> df.select('id',F.explode(F.split(df.val,'[|]')).alias('value')).show()
+---+-----+
| id|value|
+---+-----+
|  1|    a|
|  2|    x|
|  2|    y|
|  2|    z|
|  3|    t|
|  3|    u|
+---+-----+
```